# excel formula to determine workday based on capacity

Tags: excel-formula, cumulative-sum

I have a problem to build a formula to automate workday based on capacity.
here is what i have,
[table of cumulative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zQ9U.png)

I need to make a result like on column "DAY" Day 1 , day 2, day 3 and so on.. each multiple of 10 cbm.
So far, i have try this formula :

```
=IF(X8<=10;"DAY 1";IF(AND(X8>10;X8<=20);"DAY 2";IF(AND(X8>20;X8<=30);"DAY 3";0)))
```

Is there any way to do that in a simple and fastest way. Formula or vba?
I really thank you for the help.

Thank you,
Zamm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will help you:

```
="DAY " & (QUOTIENT(X8;10) + 1)
```

QUOTIENT returns the integer portion of a division. Use this function when you want to discard the remainder of a division.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
="DAY " & IF(INT(X8/10)=X8/10,X8/10,INT(X8/10)+1)
```

Comment: Could you explain what this formula does and how it works?

Comment: It is basically the same as the other answer, just a different formula, with less typing.  The int will return just the integer of the number divided by 10 and add 1.  @JJJ and now that I think on it it is not correct as the OP wants `<=10`.  I will edit.